# Will a compass still work inside a thick steel tube

Tags: magnetic-fields

If I put a compass inside the thick steel or iron tube of slightly larger diameter, maybe overhanging a few inches top and bottom, used a powerful magnet from the outside to pull the needle away from north, then removed the magnet, would it spring back to north?

Comment: I think it depends on its magnetic permeability, so the compass should be able to feel the Earth's magnetic field but won't be accurate. You can place the compass inside a completely sealed box made of pure iron to stop the needle from sensing the Earth magnetic field.

Comment: Thats interesting, I thought it might opt to go around the compass, through the pipe walls, because of lower reluctance, but wasn't sure ?

Comment: If flux lines would enter into the tube from the top and bottom, would it be unreasonable to assume they are more of a stationary thing,, taking the opportunity to relax into a space of lower concentration, rather than tiny particles trying to get from one pole to the other the fastest way possible?

Comment: Give it a try. Get a large pipe. Put a compass and an iPhone inside the pipe and record what happens.